# Shared libraries with a ".a" extension?

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am working on a legacy C++ system with lots of code and libraries that were written many years ago. I noticed that we have a collection of libraries with the following naming convention:

**libname_share.a**

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible that these are shared libraries even though they have a ".a" extension?
2. If they could be shared libraries, is there any command I can run on them that will definitively tell me whether they are static or shared?

Comment: `file libname_share.a`

Comment: If `file` returns "current ar archive" I'm assuming that means they are static? Not sure why these libraries were named the way that they are...

Comment: @manni66, that seems to work. Please post it as an answer so I can give you credit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `file libname_share.a` to check it.